# 'EACCES' error for django dumpdata on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I want to copy the database from heroku to import into my local development environment. In the past I've done this with:

```
heroku run python manage.py dumpdata -- > data.json
```

However when I run this command now I get the following message:

```
Running python manage.py dumpdata on [[projectname]]... up, run.5450 (Free)
internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, write
    at writeSync (fs.js:599:3)
    at SyncWriteStream._write (internal/fs/sync_write_stream.js:24:3)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:442:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:426:5)
    at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:317:11)
    at Dyno.ondata (_stream_readable.js:695:22)
    at Dyno.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at Dyno.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'write',
  code: 'EACCES'
}
```

From looking around it seems that this error has to do with a not properly logged in heroku CLI. However, I am logged in and can run other commands such as

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

etc.

Anybody have a clue what's going wrong?

EDIT: So far I have solved the problem by running without the > db.json at the end, and just copy-pasting from my terminal. That is obviously not the optimal solution...